# Can we prove or disprove this seemingly simple inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, inequality, summation, proof-writing

I'm struggling with this problem so any hint or help is much appreciated.

What I want to prove is:

$$\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} x_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}
>
\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_{i} y_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}},$$

Where no $x_i$ equals any $y_i$ and

$$0<x_i,y_i<1,$$

$$\alpha_{i} > \beta_{i} > 1,$$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} \ne \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}
$$

$$\bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i} \bigg) \in (0,1).
$$

**If its not provable, the least conditions we need under which the inequality is guaranteed to hold.**

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but $x_i,y_i$ cannot have equal values in my problem. The values are actually coming from a probability distribution.

Comment: Sorry for the typos in my last comment, I meant: $n=2,\alpha_1=5,\beta_1=4,\alpha_2=3,\beta_2=2,x_1=0.01,x_2=0.09,y_1=0.009,y_2=0.001$

Comment: The constraints $x_i,y_i<1$ and that on the sum are immaterial, as $\lambda x_i,\lambda y_i$ yield the same averages.

Answer (score 2):

The question is whether $\alpha_i>\beta_i$ $\>(1\leq i\leq n)$ guarantees that some arbitrary mean $\bar\alpha$ of the $\alpha_i$ is greater than some other arbitrary mean $\bar\beta$ of the $\beta_i$. **This is not the case**, as is exemplified by the following example:
$${3\over4}\>2.5+{1\over4} \>4.5<{1\over 4}\>2+{3\over4}\>4\ .$$
The condition that  $\sum x_i\ne\sum y_i$ is irrelevant since you can always multiply the $y_i$ with a common factor $\lambda>0$ without changing anything.

Comment: Can we define the least conditions under which the inequality is ensured to hold?

Answer (score 1):

Here's where I ran into trouble.

Assume your equality holds for $n=k$:
$$\sum^k_{i=1}\alpha_i\left(\frac{x_i}{\sum^k_{j=1}x_j}\right)<\sum^k_{i=1}\beta_i\left(\frac{y_i}{\sum^k_{j=1}y_j}\right).$$
As $\beta_{k+1}<\alpha_{k+1}$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\sum^{k+1}_{i=1}\alpha_i\left(\frac{x_i}{\sum^{k+1}_{j=1}x_j}\right)&=\sum^k_{i=1}\alpha_i\left(\frac{x_i}{\sum^k_{j=1}x_j}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x_{k+1}}{\sum^k_{j=1}x_j}}\right)+\frac{\alpha_{k+1}x_{k+1}}{\sum^{k+1}_{i=1}x_i}\\
&>\sum^k_{i=1}\beta_i\left(\frac{y_i}{\sum^k_{j=1}y_j}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x_{k+1}}{\sum^k_{j=1}x_j}}\right)+\frac{\beta_{k+1}x_{k+1}}{\sum^{k+1}_{i=1}x_i}.\end{align*}
Clearly, we need the two inequalities to hold simultaneously:
$$\frac{x}{a+x}\leq\frac{y}{b+y},\qquad \frac{x}{a}\leq\frac{y}{b}.$$
However, the first inequality implies $y/b\leq x/a$. If this weren't the case, then we would be able to prove your inequality under suitable conditions on the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s.